Eigenvalues of a banded matrix
I want to know the eigenvalues of given matrix $\bf{K}$, which is defined as
$${\bf K}=\begin{bmatrix}
\bf{A} & \bf{X} & \bf{O} & \bf{O}\\
\bf{X} & \bf{B} & \bf{X} & \bf{O}\\ 
\bf{O} & \bf{X} & \bf{C} & \bf{X}\\ 
\bf{O} & \bf{O} & \bf{X} & \bf{D}\\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$
where $4 \times 4$ matrices ${\bf A},{\bf B}, {\bf C}$ and ${\bf D}$ are defined as
$${\bf A}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & a & 0 & 0\\
a & 0 & a & 0\\ 
0 & a & 0 & a\\
0 & 0 & a & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}, \ \ \ 
{\bf B}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & b & 0 & 0\\
b & 0 & b & 0\\ 
0 & b & 0 & b\\
0 & 0 & b & 0\\
\end{bmatrix},$$
$${\bf C}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & c & 0 & 0\\
c & 0 & c & 0\\ 
0 & c & 0 & c\\
0 & 0 & c & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}, \ \ \ {\bf D}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & d & 0 & 0\\
d & 0 & d & 0\\ 
0 & d & 0 & d\\
0 & 0 & d & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}, \ \ \ $$
and $\bf{X}$ and $\bf{O}$ are defined as
$${\bf X}=\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & x_2 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & x_3 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & x_4\\
\end{bmatrix}, \ \ \ {\bf O}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}. $$
All values $a,b,c,d,x_1,x_2,x_3$ and $x_4$ are real values.
The matrix $\bf{K}$ seems to be block tridiagonal matrix. So is it possible to find the closed-form eigenvalues of $\bf{K}$?
If that is too difficult, then, is it possible to find the closed-form eigenvalues if I impose additional conditions such as $a=b=c=d$?
Recursive expressions are also welcome.

The $16$-degree characteristic polynomial has all odd-powered terms $0$. So it is effectively a $8$-degree one.
In the special case of $a=b=c=d$ and $x_1=x_2=x_3=x_4=x$, using Mathematica, I got the $8$-degree polynomial factorized into 4 quadratics,
$$\left(a^4+4 a^3 x-3 a^2 \lambda +6 a^2 x^2+4 a x^3-6 a \lambda  x+\lambda ^2+x^4-3 \lambda  x^2\right)\\
 \left(a^4+6 a^3 x-3 a^2 \lambda +11 a^2 x^2+6 a x^3-4 a \lambda  x+\lambda ^2+x^4-3
   \lambda  x^2\right)\\
 \left(a^4-6 a^3 x-3 a^2 \lambda +11 a^2 x^2-6 a x^3+4 a \lambda  x+\lambda ^2+x^4-3 \lambda  x^2\right) \\
\left(a^4-4 a^3 x-3 a^2 \lambda +6 a^2 x^2-4 a x^3+6 a
   \lambda  x+\lambda ^2+x^4-3 \lambda  x^2\right),
$$
leading to eigenvalues,
$$\pm\frac{\sqrt{-\sqrt{5} \left| a^2-x^2\right| +3 a^2-4 a x+3 x^2}}{\sqrt{2}},\\
\pm\frac{\sqrt{-\sqrt{5} \left| a^2-x^2\right| +3 a^2+4 a x+3 x^2}}{\sqrt{2}},\\
\pm\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{5} \left|
   a^2-x^2\right| +3 a^2-4 a x+3 x^2}}{\sqrt{2}},\\
\pm\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{5} \left| a^2-x^2\right| +3 a^2+4 a x+3 x^2}}{\sqrt{2}},\\
\pm\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{5}-1\right) | a-x| ,\\
\pm\frac{1}{2}
   \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right) | a-x| ,\\
\pm\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{5}-1\right) | a+x| ,\\
\pm\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right) | a+x|.
$$
This shows a little hope for similar closed form eigenvalues in more general situations.

Hi, thank you for the answer. If you do not mind, I would like to see your code in Mathematica. How did you obtain these results with Mathematica?

@Sakurai.JJ I just created the matrix and used CharacteristicPolynomial[ ]. Nothing special. I don't know how to send the notebook.
